# Firebase Auth Google Sign-In Reuse SHA-1 signing key with multiple devs?

Tags: android, firebase, code-signing, google-signin

I have an app using Firebase Auth UI, with one of the providers being Google Sign-In. To use this when building the app from studio, one has to put their SHA-1 key in the Firebase Dev Console. However, this is annoying to do for every single developer I add to the team. Is there an easier way to do this one-time-only?

Answer (score 1):

You can share the debug keystore http://www.kevinrschultz.com/blog/2014/02/22/sharing-android-debug-keystore/